# How to implement the EF Core IDbContextFactory in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm developing a WPF application. I'm new at using the IDbContextFactory and I am struggling to implement it. I've spent a few hours on Google, but couldn't find any solution. The DbFactory is, in all examples, already injected. But how to initialize it?

I've added the services AddDbContextFactory in my **App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static IHost? AppHost { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            // HostBuilder
            AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
                    services.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;user=user;password='password';database=db;"));
                })
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

My **AppDbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<>...
}
```

My **MainWindow.xaml** has a ViewModel as DataContext

```
<Window x:Class="SeeUs.WPF.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="Appli" Height="1080" Width="1920">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

And my **MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> _dbContextFactory; // <-- as per the .net documentation
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(); // <-- when running, _dbContextFactory is null, not assigned
    }
}
```

When I build (no error) and start my app, I've a NullReferenceException on '_dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();'.

What am I missing, please? The MainWindowViewModel is the first one, so does not get any previous factory injected. How can I initialize the first IDbContextFactory?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not actually injecting the dbContextFactory here. It should be a parameter in the constructor for your class, which you set to your private field you have for it. Then you can use it (not in the constructor - only when you need it. If you wanted to have a db context initialized in the constructor I suppose you could perhaps do that there too, but it seems odd - just inject a dbcontext if you want to initialize one in the constructor).

Comment: I'd rather see that dbcontext in a separate class or layer such as a repository or unit of work implementation fwiw.  A lot of samples for ef core are asp.net orientated. That now has dependency injection in the request pipeline, automagically providing ctor parameters out the di container. Just pasting in a bit of code out one of those will not work so well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. That's exactly the issue, how to start injecting the IDbContextFactory in the ViewModel ctor. I'll have several different DbContext instances per ViewModel and several different ViewModel instances at the same time, hence the idea of using a factory instead of create new() DbContext instances in every ViewModel. I may not gain anything by working with factories.